# Going through an array to find the biggest value, however the array index is not printing?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array, and my exercise is to print the oldest guest, and his or her name. This looks right in my head, however, it is not printing. Please help.

```java
public static void Statistics() {

    String[][] guestList = {
            {"Adam Ason", "35"},
            {"Berta Bson", "70"},
            {"Ceasar Cson", "12"},
            {"Derta Dson", "20"},
            {"Erta Eson", "54"},
            {"Ferta Fson", "26"},
            {"Gerta Gson", "59"},
            {"Herta Hson", "72"},
            {"Irta Ison", "14"},
            {"Jerta Json", "32"},
    };

    int bigg = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < guestList.length; x++) {
        int newparsing = Integer.parseInt(guestList[x][1]);

        if (bigg < newparsing) {
            bigg = newparsing;

            if (!(x < guestList.length)) {

                System.out.println("Äldsta gästen: " + Arrays.toString(guestList[x]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the real code? What language? Anyway, since `for` loop varies `x` from 0 to guestList.length-1, `if(!(x < guestList.length)){` will never become true within the loop.

Comment: To actually make this work you'll want to save the `x` value in another variable side by side with `bigg` whenever that gets updated - call it `biggIndex`, or something like that. That will then be the index to use in the result output statement following the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Store index of the oldest guest and use it after the loop:

```java
public static void oldest(String[] ... guests) {
    int maxAge = 0;
    int oldestAt = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < guests.length; i++) {
        int age = Integer.parseInt(guests[i][1]);
        if (maxAge < age) {
            maxAge = age;
            oldestAt = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("The oldest guest is at %d: %s%n", oldestAt, Arrays.toString(guests[oldestAt]));
}
```

Similarly, Stream API may be used (`Collectors.maxBy` & `Comparator.comparingInt`):

```java
public static void printOldest(String[] ... guests) {
    IntStream.range(0, guests.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(guests[i][1]))))
        .ifPresent(i -> System.out.printf("The oldest guest at %d: %s", i, Arrays.toString(guests[i])));
}
```